# Could not cancel the notifications in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have the Problem, when a user press the Notification activity is opens but it can't be closed.

Here is my code:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
     (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Good Morning";
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, time);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Title";
    CharSequence contentText = "Text";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationManagerDemoActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,0);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1,notification);
```

Answer (score 2):

try it like this..hope it will work..
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

Answer (score 0):

Set Auto Cancel to true while building `Notification` as follow.

```
  notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to write code like below

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
     new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "Channel")
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                     R.mipmap.ic_launcher_logo_round))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_logo_round);
mNotificationManager.notify(id,mBuilder.build());
.setAutoCancel(true)
```

Comment: What exactly to write about? Everything is clear there. To change the notification settings, you need to rebuild it through the builder

Comment: You can try if you know why it does not close.